# Call to a member function getKey() on bool

Tags: php, laravel, acl, laravel-authentication, laravel-authorization

i'm writing an ACl system for my laravel project and I'm using gates for it.
while I'm trying to use the gates, I see this error:

> Call to a member function getKey() on bool

can anyone help me with this?

this is my code in AuthServiceProvider.php:

```
public function boot(): void
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    foreach ($this->getPermissions() as $permission) {
        Gate::define($permission->name , function ($user) use($permission){
            return $user->hasRole($permission->roles);
        });
    }
}
```

this is getPermissions() function:

```
protected function getPermissions(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|array
{    
    return Permission::with('roles')->get()->all();
}
```

and this is how I used Gates:

```
public function index(): \\Illuminate\\Contracts\\Foundation\\Application|\\Illuminate\\Contracts\\View\\Factory|\\Illuminate\\Contracts\\View\\View
{
    $this->authorize('show-users');
    $users = User::latest()->paginate(25);
    return view('Admin.users.all' , compact('users'));
}
```

and I have this show-users permission in my database

Comment: I do not see `getKey` anywhere in the code examples?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full stack trace. If it indicates the bad call comes from your code, please also include that code